# How to change currently active window tab color in atom editor

Tags: css, tabs, less, background-color, atom-editor

I'm using atom editor version 1.0 stable in ubuntu 14.04.
my question is,
How can I change the background colour of currently selected window tab...
(means current tab..)
by editing **style.less** file?

I tried,

```css
.tab{ background-color:black; }
```

to change the tab color,

but,
this code only changed all tab colors except current tab color.

So my question is, how can I change the color of current tab in atom editor by editing style.less file?

Answer (score 10):

```
.tab-bar .tab[data-type="TextEditor"]::after {
  background-color: rgba(20,28,30,0.8);
}
```

I found this solution by opening developer tools <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, and finding an element by using magnifier tool.

Comment: Please consider adding some detail to your answer.

Answer (score 7):

None of these worked for me. Here was my solution (Atom 1.22.1):

```
.tab-bar .tab.active[data-type$="Editor"] {
 background-color: #167373;
}
```

Comment: And if using pinned tabs package, `.tab.pinned.active[data-type$="Editor"] {`

Answer (score 6):

You have to copy this code and paste in your styles.less file, that's it.

```
//My awesome tab
.tab-bar .tab.active[data-type="TextEditor"]::after {
background-color: black;
border-bottom: whiTe;
}

.tab-bar .tab.active[data-type$="Editor"] .title {
 background-color: black;
 z-index: 2;
 }
```

Comment: Worked for me on Atom 1.40.0 regardless of the theme. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Often I like to open multiple panes and have tabs in all of them. **With multiple panes comes multiple active tabs**. The other answers here will style the "active" tab in all panes, and not specifically target the tab you have selected.

The problem is [selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

**Here's one way to specifically target only the tab you have selected, no matter how many panes you have open:**

Open your Atom command palette (on a MAC shift+cmd+p) and search for 'style'.

Select the option for 'Application: Open Your Stylesheet'.

Add this style:

```
.pane.active {
    .tab.active {
        background-color: #00BCD4;
    }
}
```

Save the style.less sheet and see your changes!

*Note*: This was tested while using the [Atom Material UI theme](https://atom.io/themes/atom-material-ui), though it shouldn't matter which theme you're using.

Comment: [@Jason Awbrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6024754/jason-awbrey) - In Atom 1.17 it's not possible to use `.pane.active` anymore because the `.active` class only gets added when there's a split pane. In Chrome 60 a `:focus-within` pseudo class will get introduced, then it _should_ be possible to use something like `.pane:focus-within .tab.active` - please edit your answer accordingly :)

Comment: Works for me in Atom 1.39.1

Answer (score 1):

that's my solution for atom 1.23.1 
File > Stylesheed > styles.less

```
.texteditor.tab.sortable.active::before, .texteditor.tab.sortable.active, .texteditor.tab.sortable.active::after {
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #35404a, #4A7FB2);
}
```

a beautiful blue gradient.

Answer (score 0):

On selection of tab add a class="tab active"

and below style to your style.less file

```
.tab.active {
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: can you provide fiddlejs url

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ - create an account and try to reproduce same working and reply with your fiddle url

Comment: first of all, how we could assign 2 classes(.tab,.active) to the same element (tab)?

Comment: First find out on selection of tab, is any class is added dynamically if yes then add css property to that CSS class name.

Comment: i dont know whether it's dynamically changing or not..
But your answer is not working..!
If, you know the correct solution for my question tell me..

Answer (score 0):

Extending this for other tab types (e.g. settings, git, search results), I'm currently enjoying:

```
// mine tab color customizations:
.tab-bar .tab.active {
  background-color: #00593c;
}

.tab-bar .tab.active[data-type$="Editor"] {
  background-color: #103a3a;
}
```

at **style.less** file